# Are these all correct ways of explaining I'm from Australia?

Tags: grammar

There seems to be a large number of ways of saying "I'm from Australia" or similar.

#### I'm an Australian

> 我是澳大利亚人
> 我是澳大利亚的
> 我是个澳大利亚人
> 我是个澳大利亚的人
> 我是一个澳大利亚人
> 我是一个澳大利亚的人

#### I'm from Australia

> 我来自澳大利亚
> 我是来自澳大利亚的
> 我从澳大利亚来
> 我是从澳大利亚来的

And also I was born in Australia 我生在澳大利亚, along with variants such as 我在澳大利亚生了.

And basically all of the above with [澳大利亚](http://dict.cn/%E6%BE%B3%E5%A4%A7%E5%88%A9%E4%BA%9A) replaced with [澳洲](http://dict.cn/%E6%BE%B3%E6%B4%B2).

**Question**: Are these all correct ways of explaining I'm from Australia?

Comment: 4,6，users suggest: no 的, 11:was born 出生 （is even in C IME), can all be tested using jukuu

Comment: Don’t forget: 土澳  (if you want to be self-disparaging)

Comment: formal
我来自澳大利亚
我是澳大利亚人
informal
我是土澳的
我是澳村人

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### the first part

我是澳大利亚人  -- Correct and formal.

我是澳大利亚的  -- Correct and somewhat informal.

我是个澳大利亚人 -- Correct and formal.

我是个澳大利亚的人 -- Native speaker would understand you but it is weird.

我是一个澳大利亚人 -- Correct and formal.

我是一个澳大利亚的人 -- Native speaker would understand you but it is weird.

"我是(一)个澳大利亚的人" makes listener confusing by having a meaning of "Australia owns you".

### the second part

All expressions are valid and can be used in most cases.

### the third part

"我生在澳大利亚" is kind of weird but is acceptable, but "我在澳大利亚生了" is wrong.  You'd better use "我在澳大利亚出生".

A single "生" generally means "give birth to/happen". Examples: "A生了B": "A gave birth to B".  "无中生有": "Something happens/appears out of nowhere".

### About 澳洲 and 澳大利亚

澳洲 can be treated as 澳大利亚 in most cases.  But you should use 澳大利亚 to refer to Australia (country) and 澳洲 to Australia (continent) if needed.

Answer (score 3):

all correct except 我在澳大利亚生了, which means I gave birth in Australia

Comment: In addition, 我生在澳大利亚 and 我在澳大利亚出生 mean the same, "I was born in Australia".

Answer (score 1):

我是澳大利亚人(All Human)

我是澳大利亚的 (young girl)

我是个澳大利亚人 (cool guy)

我是个澳大利亚的人 (nagging old guy)

我是一个澳大利亚人 (lonely one)

我是一个澳大利亚的人 (a lonely nagging old guy)

我来自澳大利亚 (All human)

我是来自澳大利亚的 (a elegent and enervated princess)

我从澳大利亚来 (a tired strugglling with jet lag guy)

我是从澳大利亚来的(a tired strugglling with jet lag but still trying to be nice guy)

我生在澳大利亚 (a wild guy)

我出生在澳大利亚 (all human)

我在澳大利亚生了 (I gave birth in Australia)